# Invalid IP config on new PC

Tags: networking, windows-10, ip, ethernet

I've made a new PC for my father. (Intel I5 6500 on a Asus Z170P Motherboard 8GB RAM Windows 10)

Everything is fine, except the Ethernet connection. When I boot the system, the connection doesn't have valid ethernet connection. The W10 troubleshooter can fix this problem, however, the problem isn't fixed permanently. After reboot, the problem keeps occuring.

How can i fix this, so he doesn't need to run the troubleshooter everytime after booting his pc?

Comment: Have you checked the tcp IPv4 configuration maybe it's not set to automatically get ip and try to do an "/ipconfig release" "/ipconfig renew" then  "ipconfig /flushdns" "/ipconfig registerdns" from elevated command prompt without the quotes

Comment: I think that solved my problem. I have internet without using the w10 troubleshooter, even after a few reboots.

Comment: glad to know it's working then

Comment: apperently, it didn't fix the problem. Every now and then, the problem keeps occuring....

Comment: I suspect it's a router issue check the dhcp on your router maybe post the configuration on it

Comment: I'm still struggling to get a reliable ethernet connection for this PC. Tried to give it a static IP address, updated the driver to  the latest version.... it's not very clear to me when it happens, but every now and then i have to fix the connection....